# 'cd' command in terminal - using partial folder name

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

If I want to navigate inside folder with long hard-to-type name, is there way to use 'cd' with some kind of shortened name of this folder, to get free from unnecessary work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you know that the name is unique after a few typed letters, you can do – for example to go to the folder "FooBarBaz":

```
cd Foo*
```

The `*` glob will expand to the name of all folders starting with `Foo`, and `cd` will go to the first folder found.

The same works the other way around, or if the part you know is in the middle of the folder name:

```
cd *Baz
cd *Bar*
```

This probably requires the least keypresses. You can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it'll expand automatically.

You can get even shorter if you set the `autocd` option, assuming you use Bash, with `shopt -s autocd`. It requires you only to type the directory name without `cd` to have the shell `cd` to it. For example:

```
shopt -s autocd
Foo*
```

Of course, you can add this option to your shell's configuration file to have it loaded automatically (e.g., `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, [depending on what you use](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)).

Comment: nnnnniiiicccee!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> key to auto-complete partially typed filenames.

Comment: Must've been the fastest upvote I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use zsh, it has advanced command completion features

cd /u/sh/lo + tab = cd /usr/share/locale

Also we can use zsh hash aliases and other magic zsh functions)

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions